# Fast way to get first character of a string?

Tags: c#, string

In my class library, **a lot** of strings will be checked for its first character whether they match a specific character or not. I do this by accessing the first character via index:

```
var isMatch = stringToCheck[0] == SPECIAL_CHARACTER;
```

Is there a faster way to do this check?

**Background:**
My class library provides an interface based on strings. They will be converted to an internal data structure for which the above check is necessary. Unfortunately a lot of data is going through the interface. I profiled my test suite resulting in over 40% of the overall time is spend with the single line about.

Comment: What could possibly be faster than retrieving the two bytes at the beginning of the string, and comparing that 16-bit value to some other 16-bit value? What else is the code doing? If the other 60% of the code is nearly as cheap as this, seems like you're in pretty good shape, no?

Comment: Thats as fast as I could come up with (or use `.First`). You spent *40%* of your time on that line? That seems off.

Comment: The next fastest way would be with `unsafe` code, but be careful as the memory layout of `System.String` is not guaranteed to remain the same between .NET versions.

Comment: That seems pretty fast.

Comment: Your profiling must be off. The above operation is almost as fast as using a pointer. The internal call for the indexer access will likely translate to a pointer operation.

Comment: How many _times_ (relatively) does that line get executed?  Is it possible that you could change your process to reduce the number of times it's used (since making it faster is unlikely)

Comment: Can the string variable ever be null or empty? Using the [0] indexer notation presumably results in the IL code checking that the string is not null or empty, so if you can guarantee that is never a problem you might be able to avoid those tests somehow. (But I don't know how.)

Comment: When you've determined that 40% of the time is spent on a single line of code that's already as fast as it can be, your next step should be to ask yourself whether there's a better way to do things. Do you really need to call that function so often? Assuming, of course, that the 40% you're talking about actually means anything. How much data are we talking about here?

Comment: @xxbbcc: Actually, it doesn't resolve to just a pointer dereference. There is runtime bounds checking involved. (Basically `if (index < 0 || index >= length) throw IndexOutOfRangeException();`

Comment: @JimMischel You could be right - I only checked ILSpy, not the reference sources. In either case, the profiled code cannot be very complex if that line takes up 40%.

Comment: Post the overall intent of the method as we can probably help streamline it a bit more if we had more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is not as far as I can tell.

The fastest way would be the [`m_firstChar`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,60) the `string` class holds, but that is declared `private` unfortunately.

The `this` accessor is the fastest way. It [points directly to the unmanaged implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,717) on the CLR, so it is hard to get it faster.

Comment: Note that [the .Net 7 implementation of `string.this[]` is no longer unmanaged](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/ca82565a/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.cs#L735-L745).

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use unsafe operations, you can get a pointer to the string and get the first character that way. (You need to enable unsafe code in build settings and mark the method or class `unsafe` for this to work.)

```
char cChr;

fixed ( char* pStr = sString )
{
    cChr = *pStr;
}

var isMatch = ( cChr == SPECIAL_CHARACTER );
```

Internally this gets compiled to calling `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.get_OffsetToStringData` - this *could be* slightly faster than the indexer access but opens up other potential problems (associated with using unsafe code - at my job, there's policy against using unsafe code for any reason).

It's not likely that you'll see a significant performance increase even then, though: this code is so simple that almost anything else in your library should hide it. I have a hard time believeing your one-liner in your question uses up 40% of your execution time.

Answer (score 0):

On .Net Core 3+/.Net 5+, you can use [`string.GetPinnableReference()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.getpinnablereference) to get access to the first character of a string without range checking. For an empty string, that character will be `'\0'`.

Note that this method won't show up in IntelliSense, since it's marked as `[EditorBrowsable(Never)]`.